# Sum of distances without multiple square roots

Tags: roots, radicals, square-numbers

Here's my problem - I have multiple ordered points on a plane x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ... x<sub>n</sub>, each with its own (x,y) position. I need to find the total distance between all adjacent points, i.e. dist(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>) + dist(x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>) + ... + dist(x<sub>n-1</sub>, x<sub>n</sub>).

The problem - The square root function is considered resource heavy (it's supposed to be a computer algorithm) so I cannot take a square root for each distance (n may be very large). I need to find a way of calculating this without taking more than one square root for the entire calculation, or at the worst case a fixed number of square roots (i.e. the number of square roots is completely independent of n).

Each distance may be between 0 and 10000 and is not necessarily an integer (4 digit precision should be sufficient), which means that lookup tables will also be large and performing a lookup for each distance is probably also too resource heavy.

If this is too difficult or impossible - I actually only need to know if the sum of the distances exceeds a certain, fixed, known value. I don't really need to know the exact sum of distances, just need to know whether it's bigger than the threshold or not.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I don't know what your ultimate end is.  However, the squared metric is a perfectly good distance metric that you can use instead that is not resource heavy.

Comment: The square root function used to be considered resource heavy, but on modern CPUs, it is my understanding that it no longer is. Much like multiplication and division (which also used to be multi-step processes), square rooting is now built into the processor as a single operation. This was done exactly because geometric calculation so often required it. Are you sure it is as big a problem as you think? There is no trick that can give you the exact sum of distances with limited square roots. Either you make due with estimates or a different metric, or you will have to accept the cost.

Answer (score 1):

the Manhattan metric should provide an upper bound.

the Manhattan metric:

let $z_1=\langle x_1,y_1\rangle,\;z_2=\langle x_2,y_2\rangle$

$d(z_1,z_2)=|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|$

proof:

$(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2\leq (x_1-x_2)^2+\\2|x_1-x_2||y_1-y_2|+(y_1-y_2)^2=\\(|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|)^2$

Answer (score 0):

Considering$$S=\sum_{k=1}^n d_k$$

using the [AM-QM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM_inequalities), $\sqrt{n S}$ is an upper bound of $\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{d_k}$.

Using Mathematica with random integer between $0$ and $10,000$ (seed equal $1234$) and $n=10,000$

$$S=\sum_{k=1}^n d_k=49300823$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{d_k}=660737.$$
$$\sqrt{n S}=702145.$$